# How do I display two datasets on a single chart with chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am having problems displaying two datasets on a single graph. Technically both data points are being graphed but both values are being graphed on a single line. See graph attached down below.

So firstly parsing the values:

```
webSocket.onmessage = function(event){
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log(data.value);
      console.log(data.value2);
      var today = new Date();
      var t = today.getHours()+ ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
      addData(t, data.value, data.value2)
    }
```

this code works since the console logs both values. Next is adding the data to the end of the chart and this is where I suspect my mistake lies as I do not know how to "call" the different datasets:

```
function addData(label, data, data2){

    dataPlot.data.labels.push(label);//x-values
    dataPlot.data.datasets.forEach((dataset)=> {
          dataset.data.push(data);
          dataset.data.push(data2);
    });
    dataPlot.update(); 
  }
```

Finally the code for the corresponding chart:

```
dataPlot = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"),{
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: [],
          label: "Thermocouple 1",
          borderColor: "#3e95cd",
          fill: true

          },
       {
          data: [],
          label: "Thermocouple 2",
          borderColor: "  #FF0000",
          fill: true

          }]
        }
      });
```

I think there might also be a mistake here as I do not know how to "declare" the two different datasets.

I am very new to javascript.

So as stated above the result is one line being graphed on a chart but with both values. Thus heating up one of the thermocouples result in a graph looking like a mountain range basically.[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhOkx.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, you don't need a foreach here otherwise you will push 4 data in the dataset while you are declaring 2 :

```
dataPlot.data.datasets.forEach((dataset)=> {
      dataset.data.push(data);
      dataset.data.push(data2);
 });
```

Try one of those 2 options :

Doing things manually (without foreach):

```
dataPlot.data.datasets.push(data);
dataPlot.data.datasets.push(data2);
```

OR, create an array of data, and make the forEach on that array :

```
dataArray.forEach( (item) => {
    dataPlot.data.datasets.push(item);
});
```

**PS : for the second option, you need to make sure that dataArray.length == dataPlot.data.datasets.length**

Comment: Thanks, I did that just now and it worked. was on my way to post it here but you beat me to it :D. I used the first option but instead of using data twice the second push must be done with data2, like so:                                                                                                                                                  
dataPlot.data.datasets.push(data);
dataPlot.data.datasets.push(data2);

Comment: you are right, I forget to add "2" in the end (copy/past :p), I updated my answer